# Azure AD integration in spring boot is not redirecting to https when deployed in AWS ECS

Tags: azure, spring-boot, active-directory

I created a spring boot application with Azure AD integration. I followed the step mentioned here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory

Everything is working fine in the localhost. But problems start when I deploy the app to cloud. I used AWS ECS service to host my application.

For example I am trying to secure a rest service in the path "/myapp/mysecuredata".

In localhost following things are happening

Step1: I hit the url "http://localhost/myapp/mysecuredata"

Step2: It then redirects to "http://localhost/oauth2/authorization/azure"

Step3: It then redirects to "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=********"

The same application I deployed to cloud and lets say the url is "https://mysecuredapp.com/"
Then when I try to access my resource following things are happening

Step1: I hit the url "https://mysecuredapp.com/myapp/mysecuredata"

Step2: The browser trying to redirect to "http://mysecuredapp.com/oauth2/authorization/azure"

The process is start failing from here. Because my url is https. But it is redirecting to an http url.

Does anybody knows why it is not redirecting to https instead of http?
Is there anything else I should remember to do while deploying Azzure AD integrated apps to AWS ECS services?

Comment: I cannot propose [Spring redirect happening to “http://…/login” instead of “https://…/login”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64403718/spring-redirect-happening-to-http-login-instead-of-https-logi) as a duplicate as it doesn't have an upvoted Answer.

Comment: I found the issue. I was using ALB for load balancing. So from ALB the traffic to my containers in ECS instances will be http. This is why it is redirecting to http instead of https.

Comment: @JerinKurian, I have a similar issue with ALB configured on ECS, how to solve it or force redirect to https