# redirect_uri contains http instead of https

Tags: spring, azure, spring-boot, spring-security, azure-web-app-service

I am developing a Spring web app using Azure OAuth2.

When I run the app in my localhost, the app is able to sign me in and the redirect uri is "**https**://...../login". When I uploaded the app on the Azure app service and tried to sign in, I saw that the redirect_uri is "**http**://..../login" instead of **https**.

I have tried the following properties in application.properties file, but it did not help.

```
security.oauth2.client.pre-established-redirect-uri=https://appname.azurewebsites.net/login
security.oauth2.client.registered-redirect-uri=https://appname.azurewebsites.net/login
security.oauth2.client.use-current-uri=false
```

How can I solve this error?

### Update

Setting the above properties will set the correct redirect-uri but the problem is the following:

1. I browse "https://mywebapp.azurewebsites.net"
2. The page loads with a login button.
3. The login button does a sso Oauth2 authentication with Azure AD.
4. The first redirect happens on "http://mywebapp.azurewebsites.net/login". This is the default sso login-path for Spring Oauth2 autoconfigure lib.
5. Since the webapp is https only, the http redirection is causing problem. When I manually edit http to https in the browser, the sso authentication is happening fine, but the dashboard page of my webapp again gets redirected to "http://.../dashboard.html" instead of "https://.../dashboard.html".

I went through a lot of Stack Overflow posts, it seems that there is a Zuul proxy with Tomcat in Azure app service environment and that proxy is using http. This might be the root-cause of the problem.

I am stuck with this annoying redirection to http.

I found a similar issue [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61187974/azure-ad-integration-in-spring-boot-is-not-redirecting-to-https-when-deployed-in).

Comment: "The login button does a sso Oauth2 authentication with Azure AD" - What is the [redirect URI set in your Azure AD app](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/media/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory/create-app-registration-10.png)?

Answer (score 2):

Please follow [Enable HTTPS When Running behind a Proxy Server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-enable-https)

> The standard behavior is determined by the presence or absence of
> certain request headers (`x-forwarded-for` and `x-forwarded-proto`), whose
> names are conventional, so it should work with most front-end proxies.
> You can switch on the value by adding some entries to
> `application.properties`, as shown in the following example:

```
server.tomcat.remoteip.remote-ip-header=x-forwarded-for
server.tomcat.remoteip.protocol-header=x-forwarded-proto
```

> To configure Spring Security to require a secure channel for all (or
> some) requests, consider adding your own `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`
> that adds the following `HttpSecurity` configuration:

```java
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class SslWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Customize the application security
        http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
    }
}
```

Comment: I solved this issue by adding few more configurations.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64403718/spring-redirect-happening-to-http-login-instead-of-https-logi?noredirect=1#comment113883161_64403718

Answer (score 0):

This is the behavior when your web server is behind a proxy where HTTPS terminates.
Visit here to see the solution for springboot based app: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73071882/4455267