# How to configure Spring Security to use https redirect after login?

Tags: google-chrome, spring-security, https

A new feature/bug in Chrome (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1158169) is displaying an error to my users because Spring Security is returning a redirect in http (rather than https) even though the login page and login form are all https. I have a load balancer which forces https and then passes through to several Apache/Tomcat servers using http.

Any ideas on how to correct this issue?

If needed, my Spring Security login setup is as follows:

```
// Apply sameOrigin policy for iframe embeddings
http.headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();

// Authorization filters
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/sysAdmin/**", "/monitoring/**").access("isFullyAuthenticated() and hasRole('GOD')");
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/app/**").authenticated();
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll();

http.formLogin()
        .loginPage("/public/login.jsp")
        .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
        .usernameParameter("username")
        .passwordParameter("password")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/app/Dashboard.action", false)
        .failureHandler(customAuthenticationFailureHandler());

// Disable so that logout "get" url works (otherwise you have to do a html form)
http.csrf().disable();
http.logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/public/login.jsp");

http.sessionManagement()
        .invalidSessionUrl("/public/expiredSession.jsp?expiredId=2")
        .maximumSessions(2)
        .sessionRegistry(sessionRegistry())
        .expiredUrl("/public/expiredSession.jsp?expiredId=3");
```

Comment: Burton - I am experiencing the same issue due to the Chrome bug. Glad they reverted temporarily, but I just re-enabled the flag in Chrome and it looks like I will still be affected when they release the next version in a few weeks. I still use XML config in my app. But would you mind posting/sending your config to see if I can replicate that in XML config? That would be much appreciated!

Comment: For Spring > 2.1.x use this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64403718/spring-redirect-happening-to-http-login-instead-of-https-logi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running behind a proxy server that uses SSL termination, then you need to ensure you [set it up properly](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.4.x/reference/html5/#http-proxy-server). This typically involves ensuring that the proxy is sending the proper `X-Forwarded-` headers and enabling the Spring [`ForwardedHeaderFilter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/ForwardedHeaderFilter.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply... it appears enabling the Spring ForwardedHeaderFilter is what is needed. However, I use a Spring/Spring-security setup without using Spring-Boot, and the only examples I can find for this filter use Spring-Boot (and the class is in the spring-boot jar package). That said, any guidance on applying a filter using "basic" spring?

Comment: I ended up adding "http.addFilterBefore(new ForwardedHeaderFilter(), WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.class);" to my SpringSecurity config.

Comment: Burton - I am experiencing the same issue due to the Chrome bug. Glad they reverted temporarily, but I just re-enabled the flag in Chrome and it looks like I will still be affected when they release the next version in a few weeks. I still use XML config in my app. But would you mind posting/sending your config to see if I can replicate that in XML config? That would be much appreciated!

Comment: @B-Wieg it turns out for my particular situation, my Rackspace load balancer was not passing through the required headers.  Unfortunately, you can't change this setting on their UI, you have to change it via the API.  An example of the action to change the value is:

Comment: curl -D - -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "X-Auth-Token: $varTokenId" -XPUT "https://dfw.loadbalancers.api.rackspacecloud.com/v1.0/$varTenantId/loadbalancers/$varLoadBalancerId/healthmonitor" -d "{\"healthMonitor\": {\"type\": \"HTTP\", \"delay\": 10, \"timeout\":5, \"attemptsBeforeDeactivation\": 2, \"path\": \"/afs/HealthCheck.action\", \"statusRegex\":\"^[234][0-9][0-9]$\", \"hostHeader\": \"$varHostHeader\"}}"