# Reply URL mismatch while performing azure AD authentication in spring bot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, azure-active-directory

I am trying to implement azure ad authentication in spring boot web application.
I have registered application and added below redirect uri

```
https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx/login/oauth2/code/azure/
http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/azure/
```

When tested in localhost, everything is working fine. Below is the content of application.properties

**application.properties**

```
#disable the white label error page entirely
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false

spring.jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS=false

# Specifies your Active Directory ID:
azure.activedirectory.tenant-id=x-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxx-xxxxxxx

# Specifies your App Registration's Application ID:
azure.activedirectory.client-id=xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx

# Specifies your App Registration's secret key:
azure.activedirectory.client-secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

**POM.xml**

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
   <artifactId>azure-active-directory-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

when i deploy the code, i am getting microsoft login prompts which reuquest url as

> https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxx-xxx-xx4257-af76-xxxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=x-f62xxxd-4710-xxxx-xxx&scope=openid%20profile&state=OaHbZ_NFyiEWwHwy2V3Eg2x28yBgHB2Mz8eLJiNCWos%3D&redirect_uri=http://xxxxxxxx/xxxxxx/login/oauth2/code/azure&nonce=cvWDxorVEfhZU7TyhbsJbnePsbB3vHSh6B2TdRscUAE

Redirect URI in request header is http while what i have configured is portal is https. SO thats giving reply url mismatch error.
How can i force https redirect uri in request?

I tried adding

```
 azure.activedirectory.redirect-uri-template= https://xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxx/login/oauth2/code/azure/
```

This didn't worked as well.
Thanks in advance

Subham

Comment: Please try to add `server.forward-headers-strategy=native` in applications.properties. For more details, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64403718/spring-redirect-happening-to-http-login-instead-of-https-logi

Comment: I tried this, This doesn't worked as well

Comment: please try to add these `security.oauth2.client.pre-established-redirect-uri=https://yourappurl.net/login
security.oauth2.client.registered-redirect-uri=https://yourappurl.net/login
security.oauth2.client.use-current-uri=false
server.tomcat.remote-ip-header=x-forwarded-for
server.tomcat.protocol-header=x-forwarded-proto
server.tomcat.use-relative-redirects=true
server.use-forward-headers=true
server.tomcat.internal-proxies=.*`

Comment: Thanks for these options. Tomcat headers worked for me.. i am not getting  reply url error, but now i am getting invalid credential.. this can be related to load balancer configured?

Answer (score -2):

A Redirect_URI is the URI, where we want Azure AD or our IDP to post the response back, after a successful authentication and token issuance. Now if the redirect_uri mentioned in our request (going from the App to IDP [Azure AD in this case]) and then redirect_uri configured in Azure AD's App registration doesn't match, AAD, throws the URL mismatch error.

To troubleshoot this issue and understand what is the Redirect URI the application is sending, I have mentioned the detailed steps here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/270056/aadsts50011-the-reply-url-specified-in-the-request-17.html

You can also check the following sample for more information: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/azure-spring-boot-starter-active-directory_3.4.0/sdk/spring/azure-spring-boot-samples/azure-spring-boot-sample-active-directory-webapp

Comment: I have mentioned what uri app is sending in post itself.