# Azure Ad login redirect url is http instead of https

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I am working on the jsp-springboot application ,I have implemented the sso using azure and it is working as expected in my local sandbox. As per the document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory

I have configured

```
azure.activedirectory.tenant-id

azure.activedirectory.client-id

azure.activedirectory.client-secret
```

Also I have added the redirect url in the azure portal
I have not added any configuration classes other that these changes, I am able to login successfully in my local sandbox .For local sandbox I have configured the redirect url as `http://localhost/appname/login/oauth2/code/` and for qa environment it is `https://qadomain/appname/login/oauth2/code/`
During the sso login local sanbox login is successful but for qa the url redirect to

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/********/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
response_type=code&client_id=********&scope=openid%20profile%20offline_access&
state=******&**redirect_uri=http://qadomain/appname/login/oauth2/code/**&nonce=******
```

The **redirect_uri** is `http` instead of `https`. This url redirect happens from the azure side automatically and I have no control over so this so . Can  l Know why the protocol is http and not https

I have added certain propertis in the application.properties as well

```
security.oauth2.client.use-current-uri=false
server.tomcat.remote-ip-header=x-forwarded-for
server.tomcat.protocol-header=x-forwarded-proto
server.tomcat.use-relative-redirects=true
server.forward-headers-strategy=NATIVE
server.use-forward-headers=true
server.tomcat.internal-proxies=.*
server.tomcat.redirect-context-root=false
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add below line in the application.properties files along with tomcat server properties:

set `spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.redirect-uri-template` in the application.properties

> ex:
> spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.azure.redirect-uri=https://{baseHost}{basePort}{basePath}/login/oauth2/code/azure

or

*If needed place app url in place of localhost and port*

or try add the azure.activedirectory.redirect-uri-template : https://app.example.com/login/oauth2/code/
property.

And make sure  to  set the required redirect URLs in the portal too.

Please check the below references

**References:**

1. [Spring OAuth redirect_uri not using https - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33812471/spring-oauth-redirect-uri-not-using-https)
2. [azure - Spring redirect happening to "http://...../login" instead of "https://...../login" - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64403718/spring-redirect-happening-to-http-login-instead-of-https-logi)
3. [Spring boot application with Azure AD throws Reply URL does not match - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67582249/spring-boot-application-with-azure-ad-throws-reply-url-does-not-match)