# Issue while running the Spring boot application with Cloud run

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, azure-active-directory

In Springboot application we are facing issue after authentication with AD and while doing redirection.
We have added the below redirection in application.properties file:

```
aad.redirectHomeUri=https://icaps-userhelpertool-dev-cloudrun-kwyk47pogq-ez.a.run.app/resetpassword
```

Above url is cloud run url where we have deployed our code and same url we have added in AD also . But after authentication its not redirecting and we are getting below error.

> 19-01-2023 10:08:07.259 ERROR c.m.a.m.ConfidentialClientApplication - [Correlation ID: b396dc37-982d-4f56-ac5d-a754f24f4f53] Execution of class com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier failed.
> com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.MsalServiceException: AADSTS500112: The reply address 'http://icaps-userhelpertool-dev-cloudrun-kwyk47pogq-ez.a.run.app/resetpassword' does not match the reply address 'https://icaps-userhelpertool-dev-cloudrun-kwyk47pogq-ez.a.run.app/resetpassword' provided when requesting Authorization code.

Comment: I think it's a microsoft issue. Is AD use IP of domain name? It's not really clear.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment***

**Received the error:**

```
AADSTS50011: The redirect URI 'http://xxx/signin-oidc' specified in the request does not match the redirect URIs configured for the application '50065a5f-d3e4-426f-a4f4-1e6fbd2ed06e'. Make sure the redirect URI sent in the request matches one added to your application in the Azure portal.
```

[image]

This error occurred as in my code ,the http protocol it used is **http** But the one registered  ***in portal is https*** .

[image]

This can be set properly with HttpsRedirection middleware configuration

In spring ,this occurs when your Tomcat server is behind a proxy which redirects to `http protocol.`

Set the below configurations in application.properties with the proper url in registered-redirect-uri and x-forwarded-proto  as  mentioned here [spring-boot-application-with-azure-ad-throws-reply-url-does-not-match | StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67582249/spring-boot-application-with-azure-ad-throws-reply-url-does-not-match?rq=1)

> ***application.properties***
>
> ```
> security.oauth2.client.pre-established-redirect-uri=https://yourappurl.net/login
> security.oauth2.client.registered-redirect-uri=https://yourappurl.net/login
> security.oauth2.client.use-current-uri=false
> server.tomcat.remote-ip-header=x-forwarded-for
> server.tomcat.protocol-header=x-forwarded-proto
> server.tomcat.use-relative-redirects=true
> server.use-forward-headers=true
> server.tomcat.internal-proxies=.*
> ```
>
> and Add `server.forward-headers-strategy=native`

**Reference :** [spring-redirect-happening-to-http-login-instead-of-https-login | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64403718/spring-redirect-happening-to-http-login-instead-of-https-logi?noredirect=1&lq=1)